# How to set a state value to an array in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a functional component, `ListKeys`. When it loads I want to set an empty array of keys equal to a list of all keys extracted from storage. Here is what I've got at the moment:

```
 const ListKeys = props => {
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);
    const [areKeysLoaded, setAreKeysLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!areKeysLoaded){
            loadSavedKeys();
            setAreKeysLoaded(true);
            console.log(keys)
        }
    });

    async function loadSavedKeys(){
        try {
            var allKeys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
            console.log(allKeys);
            setKeys(allKeys);
        }
        catch {
            console.log("Error: Cannot access saved data.");
        }
    }

    return (
        <View></View>
    );

};

export default ListKeys;
```

This code correctly gets the list of keys and outputs it to the console. This is done on line 16: `console.log(allKeys);`

However, when I then `setKeys(allKeys);`, this doesn't work. I know this because line 9: `console.log(keys)` outputs an empty array.

I'm guessing I can't just set a state value array to another array but I'm not experienced enough with JS or React Native to know why.

Can someone tell me how to properly set the `keys` array to the `allKeys` array?

Comment: where are you calling ```loadSavedKeys```?

Comment: you are calling `loadKeys` but your function appears to be named `loadSavedKeys`. You are also not `await`ing it.

Comment: Yeah my bad sorry, fixed the code. The question still stands, I just had a typo in my questions version of the code.

Comment: changing the state is asynchronies, you won't see the change right after you set it.
try to `console.log(allKeys)` above `return` to see if it was changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `loadSavedKeys` to resolve first before trying to set since it is `async`:

```
const ListKeys = props => {
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);
    const [areKeysLoaded, setAreKeysLoaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (areKeysLoaded) return
      AsyncStorage
        .getAllKeys()
        .then((keys) => {
          setAreKeysLoaded(true)
          setKeys(keys)
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
    }, []);

    return (
        <View></View>
    );

};

export default ListKeys;
```

Note I simplified the code a bit since it seemed a little more verbose then necessary. They key take away is you need to wait for `getAllKeys` to resolve before you'll get the keys since it is asynchronous.

Also, you prob don't need `areKeysLoaded` if you just want this to run once, but I guess you could use it instead for a loading indicator?